# Detect sending message

Tags: winapi, applescript, pinvoke

I want to send message(i-message) from my MacBook desktop to my cell phone when I close the lid and the desktop goes to sleep mode.

However my desktop goes to sleep mode faster than it sends message after I close the lid.

Is it possible to detect sending message faster or make the sending time shorter?

I'm using applescript, but will take any suggestions in any language, because sending message is for my university subjects and other languages will be useful for doing same thing on other microsoft desktops.

Comment: Why is this tagged winapi?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SleepWatcher http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/ in command line to detect sleep and perform a command line action

I just tried to send SMS to my phone using nexmo and got it after closed the lid

```
airair2:sleepwatcher_2.2 bis$ ./sleepwatcher -s 'curl "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=key&api_secret=secret&from4249996003&to=14245555555&text=Alarm%21+Temperature+inside+the+car+is+critical+%2895F%29"'
{"message-count":"1","messages":[{"to":"14242179430","message-id":"020000004477EA13","status":"0","remaining-balance":"14.06670000","message-price":"0.00480000","network":"310260"}]}
```